# Delete Firebase Child after 10 hours

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I want to have a Function that deletes a 10 hour old child. I have this code so far but, if I deploy this to Firebase cloud functions it immediately removes all the data from the database. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('Rollerbanken/{pushId}')
.onWrite(event => {
  var ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 10 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
  });
});
```

My Firebase Database Structure:

```
{
  "Rollerbanken" : {
    "-Ku_Ywh8wElDdwNqa0KW" : {
      "Extrainformatie" : "",
      "Latitude" : "51.8306880305073",
      "Longitude" : "5.90483402833892",
      "Staater" : "Staat er nog steeds",
      "Staaternietmeer" : "",
      "Stad" : "Nijmegen",
      "Tijd" : "19:50",
      "TijdControle" : "19:50",
      "TijdControleniet" : "",
      "TypeControle" : "Rollerbank",
      "TypeControle2" : "Rollerbank",
      "postKey" : "-Ku_Ywh8wElDdwNqa0KW",
      "timestamp" : 1506016223000
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the items stored at `Rollerbanken/{pushId}`?

Comment: Of course, i edited it!

Answer (score 0):

You have `ref.orderByChild('timestamp')` in your code, but there's no `timestamp` field in your data. This gets interpreted as having a `null` timestamp, which actually has the highest precedence in the [ordering](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-ordered-data) imposed by Firebase. As a result all your data nodes get ordered before the specified `cutoff`, and are removed.

To solve this, you need to add the `timestamp` field to your schema.

Comment: I now have timestamp in my Structure with : "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp() but it is still not working!

Comment: I the logbook it says that it finishend 'ok'. So i don't understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

This how i code mine for 24hrs.

```
 exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/notification/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change) => {

    const ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the parent

    // For easier cross browser solution, get old time like this
    const yesterday = Date.now() - 86400000; // that is: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    const oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('time').endAt(yesterday);

    return oldItemsQuery.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      // create a map with all children that need to be removed
      const updates = {};
          snapshot.forEach(child => {
                updates[child.key] = null;
          });
      return ref.update(updates);
      // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    });
  });
```

Happy coding!